# Opencv bitwise_and difference in python and c++

Tags: python, c++, opencv, bitwise-and

I am working with some pathology research.
I need to mask some part of the image.`

```
cv::Mat img = imread("orginal.jpg",1);
cv::Mat mask = imread("mask.png",0);
cv::Mat clean(img.size(), img.type());
cv::bitwise_and(img, img, clean, mask);
cv::imwrite("clean_c.png", clean);`
```

orginal.jpg

[image]

mask.jpg

[image]

Its working fine with white mask, but i get different output when its in python, it's have black mask

```
img1 = cv2.imread('orginal.jpg')
mask = cv2.imread('mask.jpg',0)
clean = cv2.bitwise_and(img1,img1,mask = mask)
cv2.imwrite('clean_py.png',clean)
```

Comment: This works for me. Is it because you spelled the image name `orginal` in your code instead of `original`? What do you mean by "it has a black mask"? When I run it, wherever the mask is white the original image shows up, otherwise it is black. What is the output you get in C++ that you want to recreate?

Comment: in my program spells are correct. i wants gray part and objects other than cells of the image original.jpg  to exact white.but i got black in python and white in c++

Comment: I have no idea why the C++ version is showing you white, as it should show black according to OpenCV docs.

Comment: Either way, you can use `clean[clean==0] = 255` to set the pixels with value `0` to `255`.

Comment: i got exact white with following code.
'code' 
clean = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img,mask = mask)
clean = cv2.bitwise_not(clean)

clean = cv2.bitwise_and(clean,clean,mask = mask)
clean = cv2.bitwise_not(clean)

Comment: Ah yep, that works! That way its exactly the mask and only the mask that gets inverted. You can submit your own answer to your question by the way.